# Riemannian alignment has no effect

Tags: python, covariance-matrix, feature-engineering, neuroscience

I am trying to implement a Brain-Computer Interface system that should be able to differentiate between **rest** and **movement** trials. I am using motor-related cortical potentials for movement detection.

The method I am using is **cross-session transfer learning** via Riemannian Alignment on EEG data  as described in [Transfer Learning for Brain–Computer Interfaces: A Euclidean Space Data Alignment Approach](https://doi.org/10.1109/TBME.2019.2913914) by He and Wu. I am using the [pyRiemann](https://github.com/pyRiemann/pyRiemann) package, which implements most of the functionality.

In short, the idea behind Riemannian alignment is that we convert our trials $X_i$ from time domain to the domain of covariance matrices:
$$ \Sigma_i = X_iX^T_i$$
We find the Riemannian mean $ \overline R$ of the **rest** trials ($I$):
$$ \overline R = \arg \min\limits_{R} \sum\limits_{i \in I}{\delta^2(R, \Sigma_i)}$$
Then align **all** covariance matrices based on that mean:
$$ \widetilde{\Sigma} =  \overline R^{-1/2} \Sigma_i \overline R^{-1/2}$$

However, my Riemann-aligned data is only scaled and not actually aligned.
Here's an MVCE on synthetic random data:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyriemann.classification import MDM
from pyriemann.estimation import ERPCovariances
from pyriemann.utils import mean_riemann
from scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power


def generate_random_data(num_trials, num_channels, num_samples) -> np.array:
    return np.random.rand(num_trials, num_channels, num_samples)


def get_data():
    raw_mrcps = generate_random_data(100, 9, 1024)
    raw_rests = generate_random_data(100, 9, 1024)

    X = np.concatenate([raw_mrcps, raw_rests])
    y = np.concatenate((np.full(raw_mrcps.shape[0], "MRCP"), np.full(raw_rests.shape[0], "Rest")))

    return X, y


def riemann_align_covariances(covariances: np.array, riemannian_mean: np.array):
    """
    Aligns covariance matrices to the mean
    :param covariances: (n_trials, n_channels, n_channels) array
    :param riemannian_mean: (n_channels, n_channels) array
    :return: (n_trials, n_channels, n_channels) array of aligned covariance matrices
    """
    sqrt_rm = fractional_matrix_power(riemannian_mean, -0.5)
    return np.matmul(np.matmul(sqrt_rm, covariances), sqrt_rm)


def ra_fit(X, y):
    """
    Performs Riemannian alignment on the train dataset
    :param X: (n_trials, n_channels, n_channels) array of trials
    :param y: (n_trials) array of labels
    :return: (covariance estimator, Riemannian mean, aligned covariances, covariances)
    """
    # Use the ERP covariance estimator, as motor-related cortical potentials are ERP
    cov_estimator = ERPCovariances().fit(X, y)
    Xcov = cov_estimator.transform(X)
    riemannian_mean = mean_riemann(Xcov[y == "Rest"])

    aligned_cov = riemann_align_covariances(Xcov, riemannian_mean)

    return cov_estimator, riemannian_mean, aligned_cov, Xcov


def ra_predict(X_test, cov_estimator, riemannian_mean):
    """
    Performs Riemannian alignment on the test dataset
    :param X_test: (n_trials, n_channels, n_channels) array of trials
    :param cov_estimator: Covariance estimator fitted on the train dataset
    :param riemannian_mean: Riemannian mean computed on the train dataset
    :return: (aligned covariances, covariances)
    """
    # Estimate covariance matrices
    test_cov = cov_estimator.transform(X_test)

    # Use the Riemannian mean to align covariance matrices
    aligned_cov_test = riemann_align_covariances(test_cov, riemannian_mean)

    return aligned_cov_test, test_cov


if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.random.seed(420)
    X_train, y_train = get_data()
    X_test, y_test = get_data()

    cov_estimator, riemannian_mean, aligned_cov_train, Xcov_train = ra_fit(X_train, y_train)
    aligned_cov_test, Xcov_test = ra_predict(X_test, cov_estimator, riemannian_mean)

    print(f"Aligned train min:{aligned_cov_train.min()}, max:{aligned_cov_train.max()}")
    print(f"Aligned test min:{aligned_cov_test.min()}, max:{aligned_cov_test.max()}")

    print(f"Raw train min:{Xcov_train.min()}, max:{Xcov_train.max()}")
    print(f"Raw test min:{Xcov_test.min()}, max:{Xcov_test.max()}")

    print("\n")

    mdm_aligned = MDM().fit(aligned_cov_train, y_train)
    print(f"Aligned, cross-session accuracy: {mdm_aligned.score(aligned_cov_test, y_test)}")
    print(f"Aligned, same-session accuracy: {mdm_aligned.score(aligned_cov_train, y_train)}")

    mdm_raw = MDM().fit(Xcov_train, y_train)
    print(f"Raw, cross-session accuracy: {mdm_raw.score(Xcov_test, y_test)}")
    print(f"Raw, same-session accuracy: {mdm_raw.score(Xcov_train, y_train)}")
```

But the outputs suggests, that even though the covariance matrices have been adjusted (notice the change of min and max values between raw and aligned sets), it had zero effect on the relationships between the samples (the classification accuracy stays the same)

```
Aligned train min:-0.0008464822809330225, max:0.007592227870226339
Aligned test min:-0.0007567616196139543, max:0.007511262549941491
Raw train min:-0.009972139397447007, max:0.09223166210280183
Raw test min:-0.00907206088657424, max:0.09081586929555409


Aligned, cross-session accuracy: 0.505
Aligned, same-session accuracy: 1.0
Raw, cross-session accuracy: 0.505
Raw, same-session accuracy: 1.0
```

This is supported by the plots of covariance matrices' embeddings, which show zero change between raw and aligned (the "Day1" synthetic data is a tad weird, having both classes already separated, but it still shows that there is no change between raw and aligned). Neverthless, my real data suffers from the same issue.

*Synthetic data covariance embeddings:*
[image: synthetic data covariance comparison]

*EEG data covariance embeddings*
[image]

I would expect that the covariance matrices get manipulated by the alignment, such that it gets easier to find a boundary between the two classes - or at least that they get somewhat moved. Is my assumption wrong or am I doing something wrong here?

The full copy-paste-and-run gist with plotting can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sjaustirni/c27deda91308faf9bd020942aefec0bf).